# Canvas spark lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I would like to create a spark lines with the various lengths and animate them by moving them from center to end of the canvas and the process has to loop on a canvas. To achieve this i started with a particle system.

Please check the below code and here is the codepen link https://codepen.io/yesvin/pen/XPKNYW

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
    h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight,
    centerX = w / 2,
    centerY = h / 2,
    speed = 0,
    time = 0,
    numObjects = 5,
    x, y, vx, vy, life, maxLife;

  var lines = {},
    lineIndex = 0;

  function Line() {
    this.x = centerX;
    this.y = centerY;
    this.vx = Math.random() * 16 - 8;
    this.vy = Math.random() * 16 - 8;
    this.life = 0;
    this.maxLife = Math.random() * 10 + 20;
    lineIndex++;
    lines[lineIndex] = this;
    this.id = lineIndex;
  }

  Line.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;
    this.life++;
    if (this.life >= this.maxLife) {
      delete lines[this.id];
    }
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 3, 3)
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,.05)';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    new Line();
    for (var i in lines) {
      lines[i].draw();
    }
  }, 30)
};
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

So, How do we create this same effect using the `lineTo()`, and `moveTo()` methods? I tried with the following code (which is commented in a codepen)

```
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(centerX, centerY);     
context.lineTo(this.x * Math.random() * w, this.y * Math.random() * h);
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.stroke();
context.strokeStyle = "#000";
```

**Sample GIF**
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you just do `context.lineTo(this.x, this.y);`? Also, if the lines have various lengths, how can they all touch the center and end? Should they touch one no matter what?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach...
With lines you will get a more continuous effect:
 
[image]
[image]

The change I'm making to your code is to keep track of the start and end points.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
    h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight,
    centerX = w / 2,
    centerY = h / 2;

  var lines = {},
    lineIndex = 0;

  function Line() {
    this.start = { x: centerX, y: centerY };
    this.end = { x: centerX, y: centerY };
    this.vx = Math.random() * 16 - 8;
    this.vy = Math.random() * 16 - 8;
    this.life = 0;
    this.maxLife = Math.random() * 10 + 20;
    lineIndex++;
    lines[lineIndex] = this;
    this.id = lineIndex;
  }

  Line.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.end.x += this.vx;
    this.end.y += this.vy;
    this.life++;
    if (this.life >= this.maxLife) {
      delete lines[this.id];
    }
    //context.fillStyle = "#000";
    //context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 1, 1)
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.start.x, this.start.y);
    context.lineTo(this.end.x, this.end.y);
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.stroke();
    context.strokeStyle = "#000";
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,.05)';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    new Line();
    for (var i in lines) {
      lines[i].draw();
    }
  }, 30)
};
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing. Highly appreciated. Here, the lines are growing from center to dynamic x and y. But what we do if I have a set of lines which have different lengths, each lines starting position is at the canvas center and need to move them in x, y and z axis (ie) if one line is starting at (0,0) and moveTo(30, 120) and I have to move the complete line to out of the canvas. Decrease X and increase Y which visualize that the line object has to move in a Z axis. Hope it clears

Comment: To more precise for the above problem, javelin throw is the best visual example. A bunch of people throwing a sticks in a same place and the destination point will be different for each sticks. Here the points are only changing not the sticks are growing. But, I don't know how to achieve the same with canvas.

Comment: @Yesvinkumar Sorry I'm not sure I understand your problem, can you perhaps point me to to a video that shows what you need... also any 3d effect you should consider using three.js: https://threejs.org/examples/

Comment: Sample GIF has been attached in the question itself for your perusal also you can find in the sample total canvas movement on the z-axis (that is not required). How to bring that animation for each and every lines.

Comment: @Yesvinkumar Looking at your animation, I think you want to create an animation that creates a perspective effect, you should seriously consider threeJS for that, here is an example I put together by modifying some of their examples: https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/three.js/dev/examples/webgl_shadowmap2.html

Comment: Amazing work.. Mind blowing.. Sure I will check that threejs too.. But i dont know about threejs and also I wish to create the animation without using any third party plugins or framework. Once again thank you very much for your time and sharing. Please share the solution in threejs if possible..